# What's more likely to show up first when rolling a die, 556 or 234?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value, markov-chains, dice

What's more likely to show up first when rolling a $6$-sided die, $556$ or $234$?

The expected number of rolls of getting $556$ is solving for $a$ in the following equations:
$$a = {5\over6}(a + 1) + {1\over6}(b + 1)$$
$$b = {5\over6}(a + 1) + {1\over6}(c + 1)$$
$$c = {2\over3}(a + 1) + {1\over6}(c + 1) + {1\over6}$$
Solving, we get $a = 216$, $b = 210$, $c = 174$, so the expected number of rolls it takes to get $556$ is $216$.

The expected number of rolls is getting $234$ is solving for $x$ in the following equations:
$$x = {5\over6}(x + 1) + {1\over6}(y + 1)$$
$$y = {2\over3}(x + 1) + {1\over6}(y + 1) + {1\over6}(z + 1)$$
$$z = {2\over3}(x + 1) + {1\over6}(y + 1) + {1\over6}$$
Solving, we get $x = 216$, $y = 210$, $z = 180$, so the expected number of rolls it takes to get $234$ is also $216$.

So I have two questions:

1. Given that the expected number of rolls for getting $556$ and $234$ is $216$ for both, does it follow that they're equally likely to show up first when rolling a $6$-sided die? If not, which one is more likely to show up first? And what's the calculation that would demonstrate this?
2. Without writing out the Markov chain and calculating, on an intuitive level, how do we see which one is more likely to show up first (or that both of them are equally likely to show up first)?

Comment: If the last two rolls were a 2,3, then you only have one roll that will score the touchdown (4), and one roll that will re-start the sequence (2).  Similarly, if your last two rolls were 5,5, you only have one roll that will score the touchdown (6), and one roll that will $~\color{red}{\text{continue}}~$ the sequence (5).  However, **continuing** the sequence is more advantageous than **restarting** the sequence.

Comment: @user2661923 But on the other hand, if the last roll was a 2, then there's a roll (3) that continues the sequence *but also a roll (2) that restarts the sequence*. If the last roll was a 5, then there's only a roll (5) that continues the sequence, not one that restarts it. Apparently these two effects cancel each other out....

Comment: Note that the expected number of rolls to get `565` in consecutive rolls is not $216$ but $222$ (though you are correct about an expected $216$ for  `556` and `234`).  Also note that in a race between `234` and `342`, the former is more likely to appear first even though they both have the same expected number of rolls of $216$.  So intuition is not easy.

Comment: To the OP's question 1: if you're willing to compute the Markov chain with a single terminal state like 234, then you can also compute the Markov chain with two terminal states 234 and 556 (each with a single self-loop say) and calculate its limiting probabilities in the usual linear-algebra way.

Comment: @GregMartin Very nice rebuttal.  Rather than delete my previous comment, as I normally would at this point, I will leave it in as an example of my moderately *going off the rails*.

Comment: For given $N$, the probability of not getting $556$ after $N$ rolls is the same as the probability of not getting $234$ (this needs a bit of proof). Now look at all the trials where either $556$ or $234$ is first to appear after exactly $N$ rolls. The probability of getting to $N$ without seeing $556$ and $234$ is the same and the probability of then getting either $556$ or $234$ is the same. Summing over all $N$ we should get that it is equiprobable which comes first. However, as @Henry says intuition is not easy, and this is just my intuition.

Comment: Note that there is an obvious one-to-one correspondence between sequences in which $234$ comes first and sequences in which $556$ comes first; namely, just replace the first occurrence of $234$ with $556$. This works because $234$ and $556$ don't overlap; it wouldn't work for $345$ vs. $556$, *e.g.*, $34345\ \to\ 34556$.

Comment: @user14111 I am not sure your argument would work for `234` vs. `565` either, even though they do not overlap with each other.

Comment: @Henry Why do you think it doesn't work? It doesn't map a sequence where $234$ comes first to a sequence where $556$ comes first, or the map is not injective, or it's not surjective? What's the problem?

Comment: @user2661923 On the contrary, I think the pair of comments is very helpful (I'm not sure I would have thought of your observation when I was making mine).

Comment: @user14111 I agree that with `234` vs. `556`  the probabilities of each arriving first seem to be $0.5$ and $0.5$.  But with `234` vs. `565` I think they may be about $0.50685$ and $0.49315$.  Perhaps because `565` overlaps with itself.

Comment: @Henry You're right. Good point.

Comment: @user14111 with `234` and `565`, `56234` is mapped to `56565` but not vice versa.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni If you do the calculations rather than attempting a short cut, you will find 234 has a probability $0.53846153846$ of beating 342.  Perhaps you believe that 234 having a $54\%$ chance of beating 342, and 342 having a $54\%$ chance of beating  423, and 423 having a $54\%$ chance of beating 234, might together violate some transitivity rule.  There is no such transitivity rule.  Similarly not in [Penney's game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game).

Comment: If anyone is interested in the bounty, 234 and 556 are indeed equally likely to turn up first (they are of the same length and do not "overlap" with themselves or each other); both having an expected $216$ time to arrival (because they do not overlap with themselves) is insufficient, as in the $234$ vs $342$ example (which overlap with each other).

Comment: @Henry Yes, I figured it out, thanks. This is the reason why I deleted my comment before your answer I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, for two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)=0$, $\mathbb{E} X = \mathbb{E} Y$ is not sufficient for $\mathbb{P}(X \leq Y) = 1/2$. Even more, $X$ and $Y$ having the same distribution is not sufficient. But this situation with $556$ and $234$ is not a coincidence.

We want to show that the number of strings (of length $n$) in which $556$ appears first (at position $i$) is equal to the number of strings in which $234$ appears first (at position $i$). The bijection suggested in the comments should work: given any string of die-rolls, replace the first occurrence of $556$ or $234$ with the other, if it exists. This bijection is an involution, since, e.g., replacing $234$ with $556$ does not create any new instances of of $234$ or $556$, because $234$ and $556$ are non-self-overlapping and do not overlap each other.

To summarize from the comments the limits of this approach: note that $565$ overlaps with itself ($56565$), so the above bijection does not work ($56234 \to 56565 \to 23465$). Additionally, $234$ and $456$ overlap with each other ($23456$), so the above bijection again does not work ($23234 \to 23456 \to 45656$).